# Java: Regex pattern for

Tags: java, regex, string

What would the pattern be to get ALL strings/words in a string that are surrounded be either a leading/trailing space.

I could just use `string.split(" ")` but it would return the words in single `''` quotes as separated words. So my goal is to get all words and by also counting all characters in `''` as one word.

Example String:

```
word1 word2 'somestring' word7 word91 'word2 with spaces' word5
```

My attempted pattern:

```
\s(.+)\s
```

Answer (score 1):

`(\w+)|('[\w\s]+')`  should be enough to recognize that kind of strings.

If you are thinking of a pattern to *separate them* (to use with `split`, for example), it could be pretty complicated if possible at all.

Comment: String.split() takes a regex

Comment: @abmitchell  Good point.  Thanks.  Problem is that a RegEx you use to **recognize** strings is completely different to the RegEx you use to **separate** them.  From there my comment.

Comment: I think that the second alternation should be `('[\s\w]+')`. Otherwise it won't match the words with spaces.

Comment: @Birei  Yes,that's correct.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you use capture groups, you can perhaps use this:

```
(\\w+)|'([^']+)'
```

if your words contain alphanumeric.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/bU5pF6) (Note I don't need to double escape there but you have to in java)

EDIT: As per comment, to escape double single quotes `''` you can use this regex:

```
'((?:[^']|'')+)'|(\\S+)
```

I changed the `\\w+` also to `\\S+` to match any other character and not just alphanumeric.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. Also I just noticed a problem, how would I have it ignore double single quotes '' in a word surrounded by single quotes like: 'name''s'

Comment: @CBennett Something like that? [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/mT9jC4). Let me know and I'll update my answer with the regex.

Comment: @CBennett Okay, updated!

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
'[^']+'|[^ ]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/zcaQLAf6vd0PV-0t)

Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?3663i)

Answer (score 0):

Use the zero width assertion for word boundaries (\b) instead of \s or ', like this:

```
\b(\w+)\b
```

That will match all runs of one or more word characters surrounded by word boundaries.  Word boundaries happen BETWEEN word and non-word characters, and space and apostrophe both qualify as non-word characters, as do the beginning and end of the string.

Here's a great description of regex word boundaries: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: I think this won't match his "word with spaces" inside single quotes.

Comment: It definitely won't.  I mistakenly thought he wanted each word matched separately...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.split(" (?=(('[^']*){2})*[^']*)");
```

This splits on spaces that are followed by an *even* number of quotes.